# "shm_open" Gives "Variadic function is unavailable" in swift

Tags: swift, interop, shared-memory

Is `shm_open` supported in swift?

I can use `shm_unlink` but `shm_open` doesn't exist.

```
shm_open("/myregion", O_CREAT | O_RDWR)
```

If `shm_open` not supported in Swift is there an equivalent way to  create a shared memory file descriptor for mapping?

I have managed to create shared memory in C but still not in Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that `shm_open` works fine, it is just that swift can't use Variadic C functions.

I solved the problem by creating a new c file with the function:

```
int shmopen(const char *path) {
    return shm_open(path, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
}
```

Place the function in the "Project-Bridging-Header.h" file:

```
int shmopen(const char *path);
```

Call the function from swift:

```
var fd = shmopen("/myregion")
print(fd)
```

And now it works fine.

Comment: If you change the declaration to `int shmopen(const char *path);` then you can simply call it from Swift as `let fd = shmopen("/myregion")`.